# How to plot the non maxima supressed regions openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have removed non maxima regions from the vector "bbox" . But when I plot it shows the regions which contain all i.e unsupressed & supressed.
If I measure the bbox.size() befor & after non max supression it says 4677 & 3582 respectively.

```
Ptr<MSER> ms = MSER::create();

vector<Rect> bbox,filtered;
vector<vector<Point> > regions;
vector <int> vec;

ms->detectRegions(gray,regions,bbox);


cout<<bbox.size()<<"Befor Delete"<<endl;

for (int i = 0; i<bbox.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<bbox.size(); j++){

        if( (bbox[i].x > bbox[j].x) && (bbox[i].y > bbox[j].y) && ((bbox[i].x+bbox[i].width) < (bbox[j].x+bbox[j].width)) && ((bbox[i].y+bbox[i].height) < (bbox[j].y+bbox[j].height)) && (bbox[i].area() < bbox[j].area())){



            bbox.erase(bbox.begin() + i );

        }


    }
}

cout<<bbox.size()<<" After"<<endl;


for (int k = 0; k < bbox.size(); k++)
{
    rectangle(src,bbox[k], CV_RGB(0, 255, 0));
   //cout<<k<<endl;
}


imshow("mser", src);
imwrite("NoN.jpg",src);
```

Comment: could it be that you use `src` in a part of the code that is not here? you may try changing the color to red for example to see if it was changed before.

Comment: I did that and it worked !!! I also cloned the original image and changed the colors and used the cloned image while plotting. Thanks anyway !!                                                  But one thing I observed is that detectRegions in OpenCVin python has a different performance than the one in c++. Any ideas why ??

Comment: It depends, if you mean your part of the code where you loop and check, it is probably because python loops are quite slow, and that is why numpy and other vectorial libraries exist. If it is the function per se, I am not sure why...

Comment: @Manu BN did you solve this problem?